# How do I find out where I am on the map?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just created a map, but I cannot see my player marker on it, and the tooltip says "Display Markers: No":

[image: Map tooltip saying "Display Markers: No"]

How do I get the markers on the map so that I can see where I am relative to the map?

---

Here is a screenshot of my map. Notice there isn't a player icon (which should be near the top left corner, as that is where I am):

[image: My minecraft map]

---

On this image I found on the web, there's a little white circle (kind of in the bottom middle portion of the map) that shows where the player is. I can't see mine on my game.

[image: Someone elses map]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](https://orig12.deviantart.net/9637/f/2011/218/6/d/minecraft___my_map_by_pac_miam-d45ndnj.png))</sub>

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.14.0,
"Compass must be added through an anvil in order to show the player's position.", but I couldn't get this to work. I tried adding a compass to a map with the anvil, but it wouldn't let me (gave the red x):

[image: Anvil not allowing the map and compass to be combined]

Comment: Are you asking about the PC edition or pocket edition?

Comment: @Studoku I added the "minecraft-windows-10" tag to specify which version. I'll add pocket too, even though that's less correct.

Comment: So it's about the PC edition but the link to the pocket edition wiki and tag are there to confuse people?

Comment: That's not how it works. Minecraft (PC), Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition and Minecraft: Pocket Edition are all different games. Especially considering that the latter two, as far as I'm aware, don't even have map items yet.

Comment: @Studoku Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition is essentially Minecraft: Pocket Edition. They have the same updates and features, are made by the same people, and have cross-compatible multiplayer.

Comment: @Texenox Maps were added to PE/Win10E in the latest update.

Comment: @colorfusion Ah.

Comment: Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition is mainly Minecraft for W10 tablets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compass should be added to the map using crafting, rather than an anvil:

[image: Combining compass and map]

Then, markers will be shown on the map:

[image]